# need function like getelementbyid and getelementsbytagname for working with any strings

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I'm sorry for my poor English in advance.

I need to get elements like `webbrowsercontrol.document.getelementsbytagname` and `webbrowsercontrol.document.getelementbyid` from `httpwebrequest`. For some reason I don't want to use `webbrowsercontrol.documenttext` or `webbrowsercontrol` at all to achieve that goal.

In nutshell I want to have some function/method/routine/moudule like `getelementbyid` and `getelementsbytagname` for working with any strings.I wrote some class and methods but they were very slow and there was too many bugs.

Is there any simple way or any class or any free,simple and opensource project you masters could refer me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is what you are looking for :)

Comment: thanks a lot man. you've been very helpful. that's exactly what i wanted.